# how to escape character for select contains in bindstatement cassandra java

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

the select statement is on an index so i have to use contains 'search'.The problem is in java when i put ? and bind it with 'search'.It says
no viable alternative at input 'PowerPoint'

```
PreparedStatement pstm = session.prepare("SELECT json skills FROM profiles.profile where skills contains ?");
        BoundStatement bound =pstm.bind("'PowerPoint'");
```

Comment: Escaping a character is done by preceding with a backslash. So if you wanted to insert a quote character you would write`\"`

Comment: @Michael can you give me an example beacause i tried and didn't work

Comment: Firstly, what index are you using? because none of the standard cassandra indexes support 'contains'. Secondly, if you are binding a value you don't need to put quotes round the value when it is bound, so bind("PowerPoint") should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind value, you don't need to put single quotes around value - just use `pstm.bind("PowerPoint");` and it will be passed to server correctly. You can find more information in [driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/prepared/).

But to the Mikea's point, the `contains` may work only for [collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__filtering-on-collections).